# regdef.h: No such file or directory how can I includ files requerd by gcc?

Tags: gcc, error-handling

Im trying to cross compile helloWorld to mips but Im getting and error

```
hello.S:10:20: error: regdef.h: No such file or directory
```

Here is start of that file

```
/*
 * hello-1.2/Makefile
 *
 * This file is subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU General Public
 * License.  See the file "COPYING" in the main directory of this archive
 * for more details.
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1995, 1997 by Ralf Baechle
 */
#include <regdef.h>
#include <sys/asm.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
```

I did tried to includ it by appeding it like so

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/slobodan/rtl819x-toolchain/toolchain/rsdk-1.5.5
-5281-EB-2.6.30-0.9.30.3-110714/include/
```

but still Im getting same error, so how can I includ files requerd by gcc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soled it just by ading -L i.e. gcc -L /path/to/include/